# Delphi to VBNet Code Conversion (How to?)

Tags: vb.net, delphi

I have this Delphi code:

```
function EnDeCrypt(const Value : String) : String;
var
CharIndex : integer;
begin
    Result := Value;
    for CharIndex := 1 to Length(Value) do
    Result[CharIndex] := chr(not(ord(Value[CharIndex])));
end;
```

how can it be translated to .Net?

Comment: What encoding are you working with? The Delphi code I presume is assuming ANSI, but .net is very Unicode oriented. Your accepted answer is Unicode based. Your accepted answer will result in invalid strings given certain input.

Comment: What encoding are you working with?

Comment: I cannot answer your question because i don't know about encoding. But the answer is the same. Why was that?

Comment: In my testing, your accepted answer does not decode the string. I suspect that unless you get on top of your encoding issues then you may well be storing up trouble for the future. A few quick one way tests may not be comprehensive enough. Can you tell me what version of Delphi your code was compiled with?

Comment: Actually it is my friend's code. He is working with delphi 6. Let me try your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function that RRUZ provided (now deleted) is really what you want (and I'm still a little sceptical of the encoding issues) then you can write it like this:

```
Private Function EnDeCrypt(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim transformed = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value).Select( _
        Function(item) Not item)
    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(transformed.ToArray())

End Function
```

Comment: what's the data type of `transformed`? because I have enable `Option Strict ON`

Comment: @johntotetwoo Yeah, it is `IEnumerable(Of Byte)`

Comment: +1 your answer is short and better :), now you can remove the comments regarding to my answer.